# How to upgrade optparse() code to argparse() code

Tags: python, argparse, optparse

I am trying to upgrade from pythons now deprecated `optparse` module into the new `argparse` module. However I am having some trouble upgrading my code. I have been using pythons documentation on doing just that yet I seem to have hit a wall.
Here is the original snippet of code using the `optparse` module

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    parser = optparse.OptionParser(usage="%prog [options] hostname")
    parser.add_option("-p","--port", dest="port",
                      help="Port to use for socket connection [default: %default]",
                      default=33434, metavar="PORT")
    parser.add_option("-m", "--max-hops", dest="max_hops",
                      help="Max hops before giving up [default: %default]",
                      default=30, metavar="MAXHOPS")
    (options, args) = parser.parse_args()
    if len(args) != 1:
        parser.error('Incorrect number of arguments')
    else:
        dest_name = args[0]
    sys.exit(main(dest_name=dest_name,
                  port=int(options.port),
                  max_hops=int(options.max_hops)))
```

Now here is the partial upgraded code I was able to do

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(usage="%(prog)s [options] hostname")
    parser.add_argument("-p","--port", dest="port",
                      help="Port to use for socket connection [default: %(default)s]",
                      default=33434, metavar="PORT")
    parser.add_argument("-m", "--max-hops", dest="max_hops",
                      help="Max hops before giving up [default: %(default)s]",
                      default=30, metavar="MAXHOPS")
    args = parser.parse_args()
    if len(sys.argv) != 1:
        parser.error('Incorrect number of arguments')
    else:
        dest_name = sys.argv
    sys.exit(main(dest_name=dest_name,
                  port=int(options.port),
                  max_hops=int(options.max_hops)))
```

When I try running the code I keep receiving this error:

```
*port=int(options.port),
NameError: name 'options' is not defined*
```

In the optparse() module I defined it here

```
(options, args) = parser.parse_args()
```

When I tried to define it the same way as the `optparse` module it gives me another error:

```
*TypeError: 'Namespace' object is not iterable*
```

(I understand that the `(options, args) = parser.parse_args()` was changed to `args = parser.parse_args()` in the `argparse` module. I was just messing around trying to find a solution. I was desperate at this point)

Finally I tried to change 'options' in `port=int(options.port)` to `port=int(args.port)` Which gave me even more errors. After reading the documentation about upgrading `optparse` to `argparse` I think I might know where my problems resides. The documentation states

*"Replace options, args = parser.parse_args() with args = parser.parse_args() and add additional add_argument() calls for the positional arguments."*

So I think my problem is that I'm not adding the additional add_argument() calls for the positional arguments. Since I am new and still trying to learn pythons parsing modules I do not know exactly how to go about accomplishing that.

Comment: Your argparse `args` replaces both `options` and `args` in the optparse code.  The parser can handle that `dest_name` argument directly as a 'positional' argument.

Answer (score 4):

Get rid of this `optparse` bollocks:

```
if len(sys.argv) != 1:
    parser.error('Incorrect number of arguments')
else:
    dest_name = sys.argv
```

And add a positional argument instead

```
parser.add_argument('hostname')
...
dest_name = args.hostname
```